# InnoDB error on mariadb oficial docker image

Tags: mysql, docker, innodb, mariadb

I’m having a very strange error. I have been able to pin it down to a very simple case and I don’t know if I have found a bug or if I’m missing some point.

The thing is I need a mariadb container and I can run it perfectly with the following command:

```
docker run -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw mariadb
```

But it fails with the following docker-compose.yml file:

```
wordpress_db:
  image: mariadb
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=foo
```

It ouptuts, amongst other things:

```
wordpress_db_1 | 2016-01-11 14:33:25 140183257745344 [Note] InnoDB: The  InnoDB memory heap is disabled
```

The first message I can clearly recognise as an error is this:

```
wordpress_db_1 | InnoDB: No valid checkpoint found.
```

(You can see the full output at the end of the post)

This does not happen if I switch mariadb for mysql.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

**Output:**

```
Starting miqueladell_wordpress_db_1
Attaching to miqueladell_wordpress_db_1
wordpress_db_1 | 2016-01-11 14:33:25 140183257745344 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.1.10-MariaDB-1~jessie) starting as process 1 ...
wordpress_db_1 | 2016-01-11 14:33:25 140183257745344 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
wordpress_db_1 | 2016-01-11 14:33:25 140183257745344 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
wordpress_db_1 | 2016-01-11 14:33:25 140183257745344 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
wordpress_db_1 | 2016-01-11 14:33:25 140183257745344 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
wordpress_db_1 | 2016-01-11 14:33:25 140183257745344 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
wordpress_db_1 | 2016-01-11 14:33:25 140183257745344 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
wordpress_db_1 | 2016-01-11 14:33:25 140183257745344 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE crc32 instructions
wordpress_db_1 | 2016-01-11 14:33:25 140183257745344 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 256.0M
wordpress_db_1 | 2016-01-11 14:33:25 140183257745344 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
wordpress_db_1 | 2016-01-11 14:33:25 140183257745344 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
wordpress_db_1 | InnoDB: No valid checkpoint found.
wordpress_db_1 | InnoDB: If this error appears when you are creating an InnoDB database,
wordpress_db_1 | InnoDB: the problem may be that during an earlier attempt you managed
wordpress_db_1 | InnoDB: to create the InnoDB data files, but log file creation failed.
wordpress_db_1 | InnoDB: If that is the case, please refer to
wordpress_db_1 | InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-creating-innodb.html
wordpress_db_1 | 2016-01-11 14:33:25 140183257745344 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
wordpress_db_1 | 2016-01-11 14:33:25 140183257745344 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
wordpress_db_1 | 2016-01-11 14:33:25 140183257745344 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
wordpress_db_1 | 2016-01-11 14:33:25 140183257745344 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
wordpress_db_1 | 2016-01-11 14:33:25 140183257745344 [ERROR] Aborting
wordpress_db_1 |
miqueladell_wordpress_db_1 exited with code 1
```

Comment: `...but log file creation failed`. ... whatever's going on, it didn't create the innodb DB properly.

Comment: Yes, I can see that... but docker containers should not need interaction on the "deployer" part so I should be able to solve that just via docker commands. I guess...

Comment: try `docker-compose stop` and then `docker-compose rm` before restarting your container. This is to ensure the associated volumes get lost and that you start from scratch

Comment: Stop your mariadb server...then start you server again, adding `--skip-innodb-use-sys-malloc` to your start command

Comment: Hey, thanks for all the suggestions. I solved the error but I'm not sure how. I had some different problems with my configuration and I solved this one as a side effect. Sorry that I can't give this question "closure" :-P

Comment: @MiquelAdell could you post your custom.cnf if you use one? I'm having similar problems and would like to know what fixed it for you. A good idea would be to post it as an answer to close the question. Many thanks.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem with Maria_DB official image from Docker Hub.
It worked once with maria_DB version 10.5, but when i downgraded to 10.3, i had the same error.

The error is caused by the volume of the previous container, you have to delete it.

Firstly, stop the container (you can get the docker cotnainer id with docker ps) :

```
docker stop xxxxx
```

Then remove it :

```
docker rm xxxxx
```

Finally, delete the associated volume :

```
docker volume ls
docker volume rm my_volume_name
```

Your container should now restart without issue.

Comment: it's ```docker volume rm my_volume_name```

Comment: Then  what would you answer when all customers data gone?

Comment: @PhyoArkarLwin I strongly advise against using databases in containers with customer or prod data.

Comment: volumes are outside of containers

Comment: You're right, but it's not stable if you don't use the image Docker properly (crashs, unwanted updates like in this case ...).

Answer (score 5):

This works for me,

```
docker-compose up -d
```

then

```
docker-compose down -v
```

You may need to kill the volume and recreate it. More on,

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-remove-docker-images-containers-volumes-and-networks/#removing-docker-volumes.

Comment: This did work for me thank you why didn't i do this in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this should be a comment or an answer but I don't want to hit the character limit so…

Mainly to answer @tjheslin1 and I doubt it would be of any use to anoyone else.

I haven't used docker for quite some months now but, at some point I did manage to make this work with this code:

https://github.com/MiquelAdell/mariadb-utf8mb4/blob/master/Dockerfile

I'm not sure what was and my environment at the moment had a lot of moving pieces.

I don't have time to re-create said environment now to provide more assistance but I don't want to keep people that stumble there waiting forever.

I guess I should close the question as unanswered as I will not be able to follow up on it any time soon.

Sorry :-\